# How to solve Class "ElasticClient\ServiceProvider" not found

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

After upgrading `babenkoivan/elastic-scout-driver` package to `^3.1.0` version, I got this error message:

```
Class "ElasticClient\ServiceProvider" not found
```

I can't use any php artisan or composer commands without getting that error, I already tried:

```bash
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

This is part of my project's composer.json

```json
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "babenkoivan/elastic-migrations": "^3.3.0",
        "babenkoivan/elastic-scout-driver": "^3.1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.2",
        "laravel/scout": "^9.8.0",
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

I could solve it, deleting the following files:

```json
bootstrap/cache/config.php
bootstrap/cache/packages.php
bootstrap/cache/services.php
```

Now artisan commands are available.

(I let this answer, just in case someone else has the same problem with any other service provider)

Answer (score 0):

Try running. This might fix the issue.

```
Composer install
```